# Could you help me understand chain rule with $n$-chains intuition?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am reviewing the chain rule. So let's consider the following functions:

${a=a(b)}$

${b=b(c)}$

${c=c(d)}$

${...}$

${y=y(z)}$

Now I want to calculate the derivative of ${a}$ with respect to ${z}$.

Does that mean that I have to calculate

$\frac {da}{dz} = \frac {da}{db} \times \frac {db}{dc}\times \frac {dc}{dd} \times  (...) \times \frac {dy}{dz}$

Or am I getting something wrong out of this? Of course I've purposely over-simplified the problem, but I need to make sure I understand what the chain rule is all about and if my conclusion above is true.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see what you mean... that wouldn't affect as I've previously specified x=x(z) (yeah... I forgot about y in the alphabet, but that wouldn't change a thing). Thanks for the heads up anyway! 

Comment: Haha yeah, I just assumed you included $y = y(z)$ anyway, I should've read the whole thing. So, it was all correct then. :-)

Comment: Yes $$\dfrac{da}{dz} = \dfrac{da}{db}\dfrac{db}{dc}\dfrac{dc}{dd}\ldots\dfrac{dy}{dz}$$Whether or not you would "have to calculate that" depends on the nature of the functions.